# Solving higher congruence

Tags: congruences

How do you go about solving $x^{11} \equiv 5 \pmod{41}$.
I'm very new to this topic and have watched numerous YouTube tutorials with not much luck so far.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Find $k$ so that $11\cdot k \equiv 1 \pmod{40}$. And think of Fermat's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on @DanielFischer 's comment.  Since $41$ is prime, one knows that $x^{41}\equiv x\pmod{41}$ via Fermat's little theorem.  Now, you know that $5^{41}\equiv 5\mod 41$.

Our job is now to rewrite $5^{41}$ as $x^{11}$.  Since $5^{40}\equiv 1\pmod{41}$ by Fermat's little theorem, we wish to find a $k$ so that $(5^{40})^k5^{41}$ is of the form $x^{11}$.  In other words, you want to find a $k$ so that the exponent of $5^{40k+41}$ is a multiple of $11$.

Therefore, you will solve $40k+41\equiv 0\pmod{11}$.  Once you have that $k$, you know that $40k+41=11r$ and your answer is $5^r$.

Comment: This is rather embarrassing but I still don't understand it. I do appreciate your help. Do you mind elaborating even further please?

Comment: Where do you get lost?

Comment: I understand that 5^40 ≡ 1 (mod41) but I don't quite get the part where you have said to find a k so that the exponent is a multiple of 11. I do apologise if this is something tedious

Comment: So, you understand that $5^{40k+41}\equiv 5\mod 41$.  We would like to find a $k$ so that $40k+41=11r$ because then $5^{40k+41}=5^{11r}=(5^r)^{11}$ and $5^r$ will be the answer that you're looking for.

Comment: I get (-3) as the value of k and 11 as the value of r. Is that correct?

Comment: There are many possible solutions, but $r=11$ does work (I used $k=2$ to get $r=11$).  You don't have to ask if it's correct, you could compute $5^r$  to see if it has the correct properties.